# Can IBAction return an integer?

Tags: objective-c, methods, parameters, return, ibaction

Is it possible to make it my IBAction for a button element to return an integer that can be used in another IBAction? I want my IBAction "forward to return the integer "i" and how can I make it so that my other IBAction method accepts the integer parameter?

```
- (IBAction)forward:(id)sender {
    if (i < users.count) {
        SiteValue* s = [users objectAtIndex: i];
        NSString *website = s.website;
        NSString *username = s.username;
        NSString *password = s.password;
        int count = s.count;
        websiteText.text = website;
        usernameText.text = username;
        passwordText.text = password;
        NSString* countString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", count];
        countText.text = countString;
    }
    i = i + 1;
}
```

Comment: You can't and you can't, but if you explain the problem you have that led you to this idea as a solution, there's probably another solution.

Comment: Well, I want my other button to increment the count +1 for the giver user that is being displayed in the array. So I would need the IBAction for the increment count button to know which element in the array is being incremented.

Comment: You could store the current index or the current `SiteValue` value in an ivar. That would make it accessible in the other button's action.

Comment: you can do it with calling `addTarget: action: forControlEvents:`, but it seems meaningless to me. Where will you handle that return value? if you call button event programatically maybe it helps but i dont think this approach is best practice for you. instead use @JoshCaswell's suggestion.